# Detect Mono Build Configuration of an Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, mono

In the following 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499384/is-it-possible-to-debug-assemblies-compiled-with-mono-xbuild-with-visual-studi%20link) I read that Mono doesn't write DebuggableAttributes to an Assembly. This is a way to detect the Build Configuration the assembly was/is build with. Mono doesn't write this. Is there another way to detect with what Build Configuration the assembly is build?

Comment: The only think that comes in my mind, îs that you can check for mono core dll reference..

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy and 100% certain way as far as I know.

One not so easy and not 100% certain way is to scan the IL for `nop` instructions - debug builds will generate `nop` instructions while release builds won't.